# Reading and writing to Java file at the same time?

Tags: java, json, file, software-design

I'm trying to read the contents of a java file in json format and update the file. My initial  plan was to create a new json object with the updated data i need and delete the old one and append the updated stuff to the file. I'm however having problems reading and writing the file at the same time. I've searched all over and haven't had any luck. Kindly take a look below. What I'm dong here is searching the file line by line for the username and then getting the value of the key "balance" and adding the new deposit to it. I however can't seem to find a way to write to the file.

```
public static void depositAmount(){
    // Searching for user data
    String searchUser;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your username: ");
    searchUser = sc.nextLine();
    int deposit;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //Searching data for username and getting the deposit
    try
    {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("/Users/baidench/Documents/Github/Banking/banking.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            final String line = scan.nextLine();
            if(line.contains(searchUser)){
                JSONObject customer = new JSONObject(line);
                int balance =  customer.getInt("balance");
                String name = customer.getString("fullName");
                System.out.println(name + ", your current balance is: " + balance);
                System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit? : ");
                deposit = sc.nextInt();
                customer.remove("balance");
                customer.put("balance", balance + deposit);
                JSONObject newCustomerData = customer;
                //sb.append(newCustomer);
                System.out.println(newCustomerData);

                //scan.close();

                //FileWriter filetoWrite = new FileWriter("/Users/baidench/Documents/Github/Banking/data.txt", true);
                //filetoWrite.write(sb + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm don't do that. Write to a temp file, close the original file after you're done reading and then move the temp file to the final path.

Comment: Generally, you copy an input file to an output file, making whatever changes you need to make to the input information before you write it to the output file.  This way, if your application abends, you still have a good input file to process after you correct your application.  When the application finishes, you can delete the input file and rename the output file if you wish.

Comment: @Dici but how would I get the old stuff out of the file if I manage to do that?

Comment: I'll rephrase what I meant to be clearer: you have a file `F` containing data `D`, but you want to apply a transformation `t` to this file so that it contains `t(D)` instead. To this purpose, you create a file `F'`, you read data `D` from `F` and you write data `t(D)` to `F'`. In the end, you close `F` and `F'`, and then move `F'` to `F` using `Files.move`. We're now in the state you wanted where `F` contains `t(D)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't close the `FileInputStream` always must close your Input before create your Output.

```
//More Code
  customer.remove("balance");
                customer.put("balance", balance + deposit);
                JSONObject newCustomerData = customer;

                //sb.append(newCustomer);

                System.out.println(newCustomerData);


                scan.close();

               //This.
                file.close();

                FileWriter filetoWrite = new FileWriter("/Users/baidench/Documents/Github/Banking/data.txt", true);
                filetoWrite.write(sb + System.lineSeparator());

//More code....
...
```